# How to install vim with clientserver feature enabled on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, vim

Every thing is in the title, I want to use the `clientserver` feature of `vim`, but it seems to be disabled in ubuntu official `vim` package.

Answer (score 1):

Use vim with GTK support:

```bash
sudo apt install vim-gtk
# or
sudo apt install vim-gtk3
```